# Using express session with ionic app (no cookies)

Tags: node.js, rest, cordova, express, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use express-session for an Ionic native app, which, as far as I know, does not support cookies.

I found a potential workaround to send the auth token (sessionID) in a header request, but can't figure out how to get express-session to check the header instead of the usual cookie (connect.sid).

Does anyone have advice on this, or ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Even after 2 years still didn't got any solution. Can anyone help me this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a cookies base authentication with Ionic, just verify that you are including **withCredentials: true** in your ajax call, and that express server has **CORS** enabled. [more details](http://blog.ionic.io/angularjs-authentication/) 
Now for an Ionic app [JWT](https://jwt.io/) is a very good option.
There you could apply your header idea. 
Middleware example JWT (don't forget to verify the JWT):

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Please make sure your request has an Authorization header' });
  }
  var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

  var payload = null;
  try {
    payload = $jwtSimple.decode(token, _pem, 'RS256');
  }
  catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: err.message });
  }

  if (payload.exp <= $moment().unix()) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Token has expired' });
  }
  req.user = payload.sub;
  next();
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hmm, from what I can tell the native app isn't setting cookies when it receives a set-cookie header.